# Event Handlers Specific to This

Tags: javascript

Okay, I know the title is kind of vague, but my HTML page has a lot of paragraphs, and I want, when one `<p>` is clicked, for the color to change to green. I have the `onClick()` set for all of the paragraphs, however how can I make the change to specifically the paragraph that is clicked rather than making the change to all the paragraphs?

Currently I am using `<p onClick='function()'></p>` but I would also not mind finding out a way to do this in the javascript rather than the HTML. How an I code an onClick method in the script.js file? Thanks!

Comment: See http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html. Even though the explanation is not 100% correct, it explains how to get a reference to the element.

Comment: Can you please post your code?  It will be much easier to show you how to modify what you've already done.

Answer (score 0):

When you add an event handler to a DOM element, `this` inside the function will refer to the element on which the handler was executed.

```
<p onClick='function(){this.style.color = "#234"}'></p>
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure [this results in a syntax error](http://jsfiddle.net/zd4hfzu8/). You are defining a function without a name. Even if you gave it a name it's useless, since you are not calling it anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You can use external JS file say `script.js`. Include that file in your original html file.

In that file use following.

```
<p> text </p>
```

then JS in `script.js` would be

```
var paras = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
for(var i =0;i<paras.length;i++)
{
    paras[i].onclick =function(){
         this.style.color = "#234";
    };
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Arindamnayak/6st5anha/1/)

Comment: Since the question is not tagged with jQuery, you should provide a solution without it.

Comment: I don't prefer to use a whole library of code for one small task, but thanks.

Comment: I already knew about the IDs, but I would rather each paragraph not have an ID.

Comment: @turkey3, done, code updated, check the JSFIDDLE for live example.Let me know, if further help needed.

Comment: @turkey3 , `getElementsByTagName` , will get you list of `p` tags, in this case it is 1, so loop will run only once to bind `onclick`. If you think, i've not answered, plz let me know. All i can say you need to use `onclick` instead of `onClick`, See the CAPS `c` difference.

Comment: However please note I had to bind this to a setInterval I guess jsfiddle interprets it a bit different.

Comment: No JSFiddle is just a live demo, but can you tell me , why you need to do that in `setInterval` ? Because, this is just one time task, i guess!

Comment: @turkey3 , can you show me code for `setInterval`? If so, then that will be more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can capture a user clicking on a paragraph using event listeners, as you would expect.  Then when the user does click on a paragraph, that paragraph is passed to the function that will run when the even listener found something.

So if you have two paragraphs:

```
<p>hello</p>
<p>world</p>
```

You can listen to users clicking on them using:

```
var paragraphs = document.getElementsByTagName("p")

for (var i = 0; i < paragraphs.length; i++) {
    paragraphs[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        this.style.color = "red";
    });
}
```

So for all of the paragraphs in the document, when a user clicks on one, the text of it will turn red.

[Here's a JSFiddle!](http://jsfiddle.net/tpsz3nfk/1/)

Answer (score 0):

It might be best to utilize event delegation, where you attach a click handler to an element containing all the `<p>` tags so that removing or adding paragraphs doesn't require the removal or addition of event handlers.

```
<div id="container">
    <p>...</p>
    <p><strong>...</strong></p>
    <p>... <img /></p>
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("container").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
        var element = event.target;

        while (element) {
            if (element.nodeName === "P") {
                element.style.backgroundColor = "red";
                break;
            }

            element = element.parentNode;
        }
    }, false);
</script>
```

This approach is nice because you can click on a `<strong>` tag that's inside a paragraph, and the paragraph tag will still get colored in.